# How should I approach open sourcing a library from work?

Tags: commercial

I've developed a small and useful library at work, I have permission from legal department, what are the steps I should take before, during and after open sourcing the project?

How would I transform a proprietary product to an open source project?

Comment: Have you selected a license for this library already?

Comment: Plese define "commercial" product. Do you mean proprietary, aka not free?

Comment: @Tichodroma  That is correct.

Comment: Then please don't use ambiguous terms.

Comment: How did you go about getting permission from your legal department? I think that can be a significant hurdle in some organisations.

Comment: In relation to the above perhaps you could help answer this question? http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4378/help-with-getting-permission-to-open-source-a-small-piece-of-software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a full book on the topic of making a project open-source: [Producing Open Source Software](http://producingoss.com/en/index.html) by Karl Fogel. For your specific problem a chapter talks about [Opening a Formerly Closed Project](http://producingoss.com/en/opening-closed-projects.html).

First you have to check, if something still shouldn't be released. Is some proprietary library used that needs to be replaced? Contains the buildfile the password to the FTP-server to upload the distribution? Contains the test-data private information? You should also check if older version in the version-control contain such information and maybe you want to start a new revision 1 to get rid of older revisions with stuff that doesn't need to be released.

Next would be some decisions. Which license do you want to use? [Choose a license](http://choosealicense.com/) might help here. Add a file with the license to your code. You also need to add a file naming the author(s) of the code.

Add also a README or a similar file, explaining how to build the project. Add other explanations as needed.

Next would be the infrastructure. Do the project need a website? Do you create a public readable repository of the version control? Set up what is needed.

Finally announce the open source release.